# How can I draw filled triangles with the illusion of color?

Tags: c++, 3d, rasterization

So I have used the code of [this](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html) website for drawing **filled triangles**. But I would like to improve my game by adding the illusion of color. Well sadly I made my game for the **monochrome** Nokia 5110 screen which **can't draw just one pixel** but needs to **draw lines**. So I though about a concept like that: I could enter a float into my fill triangle function (*0-1* **=** *0-100%*) and if I for example enter ***0.5*** then it will only draw ***50%*** of all the pixels. This would be possible by always leaving a small gap when drawing lines. (*I don't care if it starts glitching at for example 1 - 10 percent*)

---

So it turns out that I am just way to dumb to create such an complicated filling method. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!

***Epilogue*** : *You don't really need to create this whole function. Just a little tip or link to an already existing method will help. But thanks if you decide to create it anyway :3*

Comment: Can you include the code you're currently using to fill your triangle? It's often easier to modify existing code than invent it from scratch.

Comment: Well I have used the code of this site: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html Sorry if it was unclear!

Comment: I don't want to see the code you referenced, I want to see the code you wrote. Your question is tagged c++, not Java, so presumably you've had to do some translation from the reference. Show us your translation.